# How to configure jetty bundle on virgo

Tags: jetty, bundle, configure, eclipse-virgo

My rap projects runs on an equinox jetty server. The bundles are started and I'm able to connect to it by going to localhost. Now I want to configure the equinox jetty bundle with some personal settings but I don't have a clue where to start.

Is there some way to configure it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my memories, you have to make a Jetty fragment with an /etc/jetty.xml or default-jetty.xml file.